# Setting up MAX_RUN_TIME for delayed_job - how much time can I set up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

The default value is 4 hours. When I run my data to process, I got this error message:

```
E, [2014-08-15T06:49:57.821145 #17238] ERROR -- : 2014-08-15T06:49:57+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:app-name pid:17238)] Job ImportJob (id=8) FAILED (1 prior attempts) with Delayed::WorkerTimeout: execution expired (Delayed::Worker.max_run_time is only 14400 seconds)
I, [2014-08-15T06:49:57.830621 #17238]  INFO -- : 2014-08-15T06:49:57+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:app-name pid:17238)] 1 jobs processed at 0.0001 j/s, 1 failed
```

Which means that the current limit is set on 4 hours.

Because I have a large amount of data to process that might take 40 or 80 hours to process, I was curious if I can set up this amount of hours for **MAX_RUN_TIME**.

Are there any limits or negatives for setting up, let's say, **MAX_RUN_TIME** on 100 hours? Or possibly, is there any other way to process this data?

**EDIT:** is there a way to set up **MAX_RUN_TIME** on an infinity value?

Answer (score 8):

There does not appear to be a way to set MAX_RUN_TIME to infinity, but you can set it very high. To configure the max run time, add a setting to your delayed_job initializer (`config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` by default):

```
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 7.days
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running your Delayed Job daemon on its own utility server (i.e. so that it doesn't affect your web server, assuming you have one) then I don't see why long run times would be problematic. Basically, if you're expecting long run times and you're getting them then it sounds like all is normal and you should feel free to up the MAX_RUN_TIME. However, it is also there to protect you so I would suggest keeping a reasonable limit lest you run into an infinite loop or something that actually never will complete.

As far as setting MAX_RUN_TIME to infinity... it doesn't look to be possible since Delayed Job doesn't make the max_run_time optional. And there's a [part in the code](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/blob/719b628bdd54566f80ae3a99c4a02dd39d386c07/lib/delayed/job.rb#L168) where a `to_i` conversion is done, which wouldn't work with infinity:

```
[2] pry(main)> Float::INFINITY.to_i
# => FloatDomainError: Infinity
```